Trouble Completing OAuth Authorization for Google Calendar actions on iOS ChatGPT App (Works on Web/Desktop)
I'm integrating Google Calendar with ChatGPT by setting up a GPT Action following the OpenAI Cookbook tutorial. While the OAuth authorization works seamlessly on web and desktop applications, I'm encountering issues on the iOS ChatGPT app.
Issue:
When I attempt to "Sign in with Google" on the iOS ChatGPT app, the OAuth login process fails to complete. The authorization never finalizes, leaving me unable to access my calendar events. In contrast, the same process works flawlessly on web and desktop platforms.
Steps to Reproduce:

Initiate the Google OAuth flow by clicking "Sign in with Google" within the ChatGPT iOS app.
Authenticate using Google credentials and grant the necessary permissions.
Observe that the authorization does not complete, and the app fails to retrieve calendar data.

What I've Tried:

Redirect URI: Verified that my redirect URI matches the one provided by ChatGPT and is listed as an authorized redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Scopes & OAuth Configuration: Ensured that I'm using the same scopes and OAuth settings that work on desktop and web.
App Update: Updated the ChatGPT iOS app to the latest version to rule out any potential bugs.
Network Settings: Confirmed that no VPNs are interfering with the connection.
Test Users: Added my email to the test users in the Google OAuth consent screen within the Google Cloud Console.

Additional Observations:

The issue occurs only during the initial OAuth connection initiated from the iOS app.
Subsequent attempts to use OAuth from the web or desktop allow temporary access on mobile, but eventually require re-initialization, which then fails when attempted from iOS.
Hypothesis: The iOS ChatGPT app uses an embedded Safari browser for authentication. It seems there's a problem with how this embedded browser handles the OAuth flow, preventing proper redirection back to the ChatGPT app. Attempting to open the authentication in another browser (e.g., Chrome) doesn't resolve the issue.

Error Message:
After redirecting back to ChatGPT post-authentication, I receive the following error:
Step 1:

Step 2:

Step 3:

